# Excel format to only prepend character, without changing number format

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to define a custom number format to simply prepend `+` or `-` to positive and negative numbers, and I want to use the default number formatting that only includes as many places or decimals as necessary.

For example general format:

```
8
-5.25
6.5
-2.75
```

would instead be displayed as:

```
+ 8
- 5.25
+ 6.5
- 2.75
```

The closest I've gotten so far is `+ #.###; - #.###;`, but this still attached trailing decimal points to whole numbers. How can I just drop in the general number format after the sign?

Comment: I think you'll have a hard time eliminating the trailing decimal point with your other constraints.  All of the Excel number wildcards seem to leave them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use custom format

```
+ General;- General
```

[image]

This also works in Excel 2003

[image]

and in Excel 2007

[image]

and in 2013

[image]

I don't have ready access to any earlier versions but I don't doubt that this will also work in Excel 2000 and previous.

Comment: YES!!! Awesome.

Comment: +1 Nice solution to an issue that people have gone through all sorts of contortions to address (e.g., worksheet change event macro). Do you  know whether it works in older (pre-2010 or 2007) versions of Excel?

Comment: I see no reason why this would not work in any current version. Confirmed and tested in 2003 and 2010. Need to find a box with 2007 and 2013.

Comment: tested and added screenshots for 2007 and 2013.